# How can I disable this done button until these two text fields have values?

Tags: swift, button, tableview

My goal is for the done button to be disabled while both of these text fields are empty. I have the logic for the top button, but as soon the top text field "taskNameTextFIeld" has at least one character, the done button is enabled. I don't want users to be able to press done while "timeTextField" is empty. You can see what I have so far in textField().

[image]

```
import UIKit

protocol AddNewTaskViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func addNewTaskViewControllerDidCancel(_ controller: AddNewTaskViewController)
    func addNewTaskViewController(_ controller: AddNewTaskViewController, 
    didFinishAdding item: TaskData)
}

class AddNewTaskViewController: UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var taskNameTextFIeld: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var timeTextFIeld: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var doneBarButton: UIBarButtonItem!

weak var delegate: AddNewTaskViewControllerDelegate?

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let oldText = textField.text! as NSString
    let newText = oldText.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string) as NSString
    doneBarButton.isEnabled = newText.length > 0
    return true
}

@IBAction func cancel(_ sender: Any) {
    delegate?.addNewTaskViewControllerDidCancel(self)
}

@IBAction func done(_ sender: Any) {
    let item = TaskData()
    item.task = taskNameTextFIeld.text!
    item.time = timeTextFIeld.text!

    delegate?.addNewTaskViewController(self, didFinishAdding: item)
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ TextField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    return false
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
    return nil
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.taskNameTextFIeld.delegate = self;
    self.timeTextFIeld.delegate = self;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
}
```

Comment: What actually happens?

Comment: When I fill out the top text field, the doneBarButton becomes enabled, I need it to stay disabled until both fields have text entered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you aren't checking **both** fields. Change:

```
doneBarButton.isEnabled = newText.length > 0
```

To an actual check of things:

```
if taskNameTextFIeld.text.length > 0 && timeTextFIeld.text.length > 0 {
    doneBarButton.isEnabled = newText.length > 0
}
```

Also, I'd recommend changing the names of both text fields to be `Field` and not `Field`.

Comment: This code won't work properly in the shouldChangeCharactersIn method.

Comment: I did this and I'm still having the same issue. I also used `(taskNameTextFIeld.text?.characters.count)! > 0` because the textfields don't have a length member apparently. Also thanks for pointing out that typo

Comment: I made a typo in my own since I fixed it, it is now working, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is some detail on how I solved the problem. Text fields themselves did not have a length member so I compared character count instead.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let oldText = textField.text! as NSString
    let newText = oldText.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string) as NSString
    //doneBarButton.isEnabled = newText.length > 0
    if (taskNameTextFIeld.text?.characters.count)! > 0 && (timeTextFIeld.text?.characters.count)! > 0 {
        doneBarButton.isEnabled = newText.length > 0
    }
    return true
}
```